# Cloud Function triggered by multiple firestore databases

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, event-arc

Firestore Multiple Databases currently in preview, I'm wondering is it possible to trigger a cloud function from multiple firestore databases.

- I have tried by replacing the database name with * and {databaseNname} in the function config of the firebase function.
- I have tried creating event-arc trigger with a audit log trigger and a pathpattern

But nothing is working

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question in the Firestore Google Group, I god this answer:

> You need to deploy your trigger separately for each Firestore database.